# Is it possible to make one SQL SELECT statement to one table and get back two columns with each their condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a person table:

```
| id | name | age (18-20) | gender |
------------------------------------
| 1  | Kyle |      20     |   male |
| 2  | Jane |      19     | female |
| 3  | Brian|      19     |   male |
| 4  | Chris|      19     |   male |
| 5  | Mary |      19     | female |
| 6  | Kate |      20     | female |
```

I want to make a SELECT where I get each gender in a their own column, and the rows should display the age count, like this:

```
| male | female |
-----------------
|   0  |    0   |
|   2  |    2   |
|   1  |    1   |
```

The first row shows that there is 2 males that's 18 years old and one female. The seconds shows 19, etc. I just want to understand the logic so the order (ASC, DESC) and details like that is not important.

Comment: A bit silly putting the age in a database, you're going to have to change it every year. You should store the DOB and calculate it off that

Comment: @Charlieface I completely agree. This is just an example for me to understand the logic, it's not my actual table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple group by and conditional aggregation :

```
select age 
   , count(case when gender = 'male' then 1 end) male
   , count(case when gender = 'female' then 1 end) female
from  person
group by age
```

then from comments:

> Is It possible to always make it return the result for all 3 ages. Meaning if no one was 18 it should still return all 3 rows with 0

```
select ages.age 
   , count(case when gender = 'male' then 1 end) male
   , count(case when gender = 'female' then 1 end) female
from  (VALUES  (18) , (19) , (20)) ages(age)  
left join person p
  on ages.age = p.age
group by ages.age
```

Comment: Okay, that works but is it possible to always make it return the result for all 3 ages. Meaning if no one was 18 it should still return all 3 rows with 0 in both columns for the "18 years old" count? I have edited the post so you can see what I mean.

Comment: Thank you very much!!